# Text from another table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cant find my error, so i hope you can help me.

Over the matches table, i want to load the title from the teams table.

Here you can see what i have tried. But i can only see the `teams_id 1` on view and not the title. How i can show the title from the teams table?

EDIT// If i add this to my view, i see the title. But i dont need a dropdown. How i can show the result only without a dropdown menu.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('teams_id', dd2menu('teams', array('teams_id' => 'title')), set_value('teams_id', $item->teams_id), 'class="form-control"') ?>
```

view:

```
<?php echo $item->teams_id ?>
```

controller:

```
$this->{$this->model}->custom_select = 'matches.*, teams.title as teams';
$this->{$this->model}->joins = array( 'teams' => array('teams.teams_id = matches.teams_id', 'inner'));
```

table teams

```
teams_id | title
----------------
     1   |  name
```

table matches

```
match_id | teams_id
----------------
33       | 1
```

Comment: I think you mad a mistake in assignment.. It should be like - <pre>$this->{$this->model}->custom_select = 'matches.*, teams.title as title';"</pre>.. Please note "as title"..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are output is an array you should tried to `print_r` first and see what is the actual output.

`<?php echo print_r($item); ?>`

After you see what you want to output the proper way to get an array is below.

`<?php echo $item['teams'];?>`

if the teams is actually there to output.

Comment: Ok, so i see only the ID 1. But i want the title "name" from the other sql table.